# Cloudera management services stopped

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

Anyone please help me.
My cloudera works just well, until now almost all services stopped, as well as the `Cloudera Management service` (all inside like `Host Monitor, Every Server, Activity Monitor`.. are down).
I tried to restart `Host Monitor`, also it failed, with the Stderr says:

```
+ echo 'Executing: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle//bin/java' -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:+UseParNewGC -Dmgmt.log.file=mgmt-cmf-mgmt-HOSTMONITOR-trafficdata1.sis.uta.fi.log.out -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfirehose.schema.dir=/usr/share/cmf/schema -Xms1073741824 -Xmx1073741824 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/lib64/cmf/service/common/killparent.sh -cp '/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/1528-cloudera-mgmt-HOSTMONITOR:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar:/usr/share/cmf/lib/postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar:/usr/share/java/oracle-connector-java.jar:/usr/share/cmf/lib/*' com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.Main --pipeline-type HOST_MONITORING --mgmt-home /usr/share/cmf
+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle//bin/java -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:+UseParNewGC -Dmgmt.log.file=mgmt-cmf-mgmt-HOSTMONITOR-trafficdata1.sis.uta.fi.log.out -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfirehose.schema.dir=/usr/share/cmf/schema -Xms1073741824 -Xmx1073741824 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/lib64/cmf/service/common/killparent.sh -cp '/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/1528-cloudera-mgmt-HOSTMONITOR:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar:/usr/share/cmf/lib/postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar:/usr/share/java/oracle-connector-java.jar:/usr/share/cmf/lib/*' com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.Main --pipeline-type HOST_MONITORING --mgmt-home /usr/share/cmf
/usr/lib64/cmf/service/mgmt/mgmt.sh: line 58: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle//bin/java: No such file or directory
```

However, I checked `JAVA_HOME` environment through terminal using `'echo $JAVA_HOME'`, which shows: `"/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk"`
I think this is maybe the reason, if yes, anyone can explain me how to change the `JAVA_HOME` environment setting? Or maybe there are other resaons, please help.
(I remembered I changed some configuration through web UI also checked some configuration through terminal like `.bashrc` and so on, but forgot what I have changed exactly, is there anywhere that I can checked the changes?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have solved, just set JAVA_HOME environment following http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cm_ig_java_home_location.html